# SSIS Excel Connection Manager Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, connection, bids

I am trying to create an Excel Connection Manager from an Excel file that has 19,852 rows. After I select the file and the Excel Sheet and click ok, I get the following error:

```
value does not fall within the expected range
```

How do I fix this error? Let me know if you need more information!

Thanks

Comment: are you using parameters on the component?

Comment: Is there any value in your excel sheet which is encrypted or does not fall into ssis data type range .Try removing few of the rows and then preview the data in your excel conn manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply the hints from this post: [SSIS Excel Import Forcing Incorrect Column Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542497/ssis-excel-import-forcing-incorrect-column-type)

Excel connector is famous for missing the correct data column types.