# SSIS Excel import turns strings to NULL

Tags: excel, import, ssis

I dynamically define a user variable xlsFileName and xlsWorksheetName. In the excel connection manager the excelfilepath then points to xlsFileName. In the excel source I use the excel connection manager and access mode table name or view name variable where I then use the Worksheet Variable xlsWorksheetName. This all works fine and data get's loaded as it should.

But now I noticed that in one of my columns (which holds numbers and strings, most of them are numbers) all strings will be imported as NULL which is totally wrong. The target data type for this column is varchar.

What can I do to force SSIS to import from excel the real values which are there in the source?

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542497/ssis-excel-import-forcing-incorrect-column-type

Comment: nope, imex=1 doesn't help, still NULLs...

Comment: Yes most answers are saying that. I personally don't import directly from Excel, but convert it into pipe-delimited txt first.

Comment: any other ideas? i really need to get this working :( i tried to do a sql like command where i convert the column with CSTR (since its access sql) but still no luck... you said you convert it into pipe-delimited txt first, do you do this in ssis and if so, how? i would also convert to csv or something else as long as i can do it within ssis. business users only know excel, so this is why i can't change the original source file.

Comment: You would be creating a new temporary file that will be used and discarded at the end of the package. My approach was to call an external Excel to Txt console application from within SSIS, passing it the necessary variables like file location. The console app returns the file path of the converted file at completion, which I map to a variable and use as the source of my Dataflow. The essence of the process is the conversion application.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem and then I tried tweaking all the properties of Excel Task of SSIS , mainly in the Advanced Editor . Like changing the data types of Input/External Columns. Try changing the columns datatype to **Numeric** . Try this First. If at all this doesn't Work

Try changing the properties of Excel Connection Manager like **Excel Version** from **97-2003** to **2007**

[image]

I have excel files in **97-2003 format** and even if the connection manager version is changed to **2007** , there wasn't any data loss and all the strings which returned **NULL** before now returned every string and number.

before changing the Excel Version : i.e. **97-2003**

[image]

After changing the version to **2007**

[image]

Please try this and let us know here