# Data importing from a grouped table in Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

[image]

I have a data like the below image in an excel to be extracted into SQL server. I need the date and only the rows starting from Product code. Can some one please help me on the way to extract this data.

When i extract the whole data the as it is, all the header and the data gets extracted into the table as a row value.

also the table is filled with null due to grouping in the excel.

Can some one help me on how i can extract only the date part and the data starting from Product code.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the IMEX=1 import. See this SO [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542497/ssis-excel-import-forcing-incorrect-column-type

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. Bca i do not have the data type issue. My issue is that  i would like to skip the null rows.

Comment: In that case can't you filter them with a conditional split?

Comment: I finally decided to solve this problem by extracting the data with row ID. And to the necessary filtering in the SQL server.