# SSIS importing percentage column from Excel displaying as NULL in database

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have an ETL process set up to take data from an Excel spreadsheet and store it in a database using SSIS. However, one of the columns in the the Excel file is formatted as a percent, and it will sometimes erroneously be stored as a NULL value in the database, as if there was some sort of translation error.

Pictured is the exact format being used for the column in Excel.

[image: Excel Percent Column Format]

Interestingly, these percent values do load properly on some days, but for some reason one particular Excel sheet I was given as an example of this issue will not load any of them at all when put through the SSIS processor.

In Excel, these values will show up like "50.00%", and when the SSIS processor is able to translate them properly it will display as the decimal equivalent in the database, "0.5", which is what I want instead of the NULL values. The data type I am using in SSIS for this is Unicode string [DT_WSTR], and it is saved as an NVARCHAR in the database.

Any insight as to why these values will sometimes not display/translate as intended? I have tried messing around with the data types in SSIS/SQL Server, but it has either resulted in no change or error. When I put test values in the Excel sheet, such as "test" to see if it is importing anything at all from this column, it does seem to work (just not for the percent numbers that I need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the "mixed data types" that were present in the first few rows of my data (the "mixed" part being blank fields), which would explain why some sheets would work and others wouldn't.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/542573/11815822

Setting the connection string to accommodate for this fixed the issue.