# Failed Because Truncation Occurred

Tags: excel, ssis

I am getting the following error on my SSIS import process.

"Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[XYZ]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[XYZ]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component."

I understand the issue relates to the column XYZ being too large, and it being truncated.  But for the life of me, I cannot figure out the solution.

In my database, this column is set to NVARCHAR(512).  The column in question only has a max value of 265, but something in my SSIS package isn't updating to the column size.

In my Data Source step, I did the following:

- Right Mouse Click and go into Advanced Editor
- Went to Input and Output Properties
- Checked column in question in "Output Columns" and the Length is set to 512 Unicode string [DT_WSTR]
- However, I noticed in the "External Columns" portion, the Length is only 255.  However, I cannot seem to update this value, as every time I change it to 512, it reverts back to 255

As such, I am not sure if the "External Column" in the Advanced Editor is the issue and if it is, how to update the value and keep it from reverting back to the original 255 value.

Comment: Take your spreadsheet and in the first 8 rows of data, replace the values of XYZ column to be a 265 characters of data. Save, close the spreadsheet. Close and reopen the package. you likely have a yellow exclamation point sitting on the Excel Source, Double click it and it should auto-update metadata. If the length is what you want, then you're all set. Save and run the package with the unaltered Excel file.  Did that work?

Comment: I cant find it currently but there was something you could edit in connection string seating/parameter to have Excel scan more rows of data than the first 8 like suggested above.

Comment: This may be it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542497/ssis-excel-import-forcing-incorrect-column-type

Comment: Correct, `IMEX=1` in the extended properties will allow it to scan beyond the initial 8 rows to interpret the data types. However, it seems like the problem here is that it correctly identifies the type as string, just not the proper starting length. Rather than mucking with extended properties, a faster win can be to modify the source file to report minimum column width. /shrug

Answer (score 0):

The answer was what is mentioned above.  Just wanted to close out the question and mark it as answered.