# SSIS receive Excel column as DT_IMAGE

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-data-types

Good day to you, Experts.

I'm stuck on a problem I'm having with an Excel 97-02 .xls file.
When adding it as a source in SSIS, I'm getting an External Columns Datatype of **DT_IMAGE** .
The column represents an ID and is numeric only. I can't extract and work with the data because of the **DT_IMAGE** datatype.
Setting `IMEX=1` didn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @llya it is good to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to read more about asking questions, accepting answers, and you will get your first *"informed"* badge

Answer (score 1):

Reading Excel files in SSIS is done using OLEDB provider which may not detect the appropriate Excel column type.

There are many other questions mentioning similar issues such as:

- [SSIS Excel Import Forcing Incorrect Column Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542497/ssis-excel-import-forcing-incorrect-column-type)
- [SSIS Excel Data Source - Is it possible to override column data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540823/ssis-excel-data-source-is-it-possible-to-override-column-data-types)
- [SSIS keeps force changing excel source string to float](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39252/ssis-keeps-force-changing-excel-source-string-to-float/149378#149378)

As you mentioned in the question, if you added `;Extended Properties="IMEX=1"` to the connectionstring with no luck then i think there is 4 things you can try:

1. Sorting column data inside Excel
2. [Change the entire column formatting manually](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/apply-specific-number-format-data-type-in-excel-2010/)
3. Go to the advanced editor on the Excel source >> into the output column list and set the type for each of the columns.
4. Adding `IMEX=1; MAXROWSTOSCAN=0` to the connectionstring
5. If nothing of the above steps worked then you should **[save the Excel sheet as a text file](https://support.microsoft.com/ar-sa/help/236605/prb-dts-wizard-may-not-detect-excel-column-type-for-mixed-data-in-sql)** and then you use Flat File Connection manager

Comment: Unless someone is forcing my hand otherwise, I'm skipping to step 5 100% of the time.

Comment: @JacobH 100% true